# ajax_command_invoke addClass changes lost after form validation

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I am currently trying to build a form which has a series of select elements, each of which triggers display of a textarea specific to that select element which is initially hidden.

Currently the select element has a callback to a function which is using ajax_command_css (to toggle the view of the textbox) and also ajax_command_invoke to add a class to the textbox so that it is still shown after validation errors are triggered. Currently after a validation event, the classes added using this method are lost so the textboxes remain hidden.

Select and textareas are created like this:

```
$form['2og_select'] = array(
    '#prefix' => $blurb,
    '#title' => t('2OG'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
      t(' '),t('1'),t('2'),t('3'),t('4'),t('5'),
    ),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'show_comments_js',
      'event' => 'change',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      'progress' => array(
        'message' => '',
        'type' => 'throbber',
      ),
    ),
  );
  $form['2og_textarea'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#maxlength' => 512,
    '#suffix' => ('<div style="clear:both;"></div>'),
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('comments'),
    ),
  );
```

Callback function looks like this:

```
function show_comments_js($form, &$form_state) {

  $commands = array();

  $triggerName = $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'];
  $triggerValue = $form_state['triggering_element']['#value'];

  $name_bits = explode('_',$triggerName);
  if ($triggerValue != '0') {
    $commands[] = ajax_command_css('#edit-' . $name_bits[0]  . '-textarea', array('display' => 'inline'));
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-' . $name_bits[0]  . '-textarea', addClass, array('show-comments'));
  }
  else {
    $commands[] = ajax_command_css('#edit-' . $name_bits[0]  . '-textarea', array('display' => 'none'));
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-' . $name_bits[0]  . '-textarea', removeClass, array('show-comments'));
  }

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

I have also noticed that the id of the form has '--2' appended to it after submitting, could this be related?

Would using an ajax validation tied to the submit button have the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to get round this was to use the highly useful #states property in the Form API - set the textarea display to be dependent on the select box having a value other than 0 selected. Did the trick without too much hassle!

For an example of this go to

[form_example_states_form documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example--form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the IDs of an element change when it's being reloaded using AJAX. That's supposed to be a feature. :/ You might try using a class to target your textareas instead.

Comment: Cheers, that's confirmed what I suspected. The only problem is, the form isn't retaining the classes added between submitting and validating.